# How to move the object to the position of mouse(opengl)

Tags: opengl

As title, I am trying to do this by **glTranslate**(). So I have to know the relation between window screen coordinates and OpenGL coordinate.

I could get the mouse position in the window screen coordinate by **glutMouseFunc**(). And according to what I have found online, I need the function **gluUnProject**() to transfer the window screen coordinate from glutMouseFunc() to OpenGL coordinate.

The result is correct without the function **gluLookAt**() and **glFrustum**(). But with these two function, I got complete wrong answers.

This is the initial setting:

```
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT );
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();
gluLookAt(1.9, 1.75, 1.7, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0, 1, 0);
glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_LINE);/*show all planes of the polygon by lines*/
glPointSize(20.0);
glBegin(GL_POINTS);
    glVertex3f(0.5, 0.5, 0.5);
    glVertex3f(0, 0, 0);
    glVertex3f(0.25, 0.25, 0.25);
glEnd();
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
glFrustum(-0.4, 0.4, -0.4, 0.4, 1.1, 10);
glutSwapBuffers();
```

In glutMouseFunc(mouse):

```
void mouse(int button, int state, int mouse_x, int mouse_y){
if(button == GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON && state == GLUT_DOWN){
    int viewport[4];
    double modelview[16];
    double projection[16];
    double windowX,windowY,z_cursor;
    double x,y,z;
    glGetIntegerv(GL_VIEWPORT, viewport);
    glGetDoublev(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, modelview);
    glGetDoublev(GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX, projection);
    windowX= (double)mouse_x;
    windowY= (double)viewport[3]-(double)mouse_y;
    glReadPixels(windowX, windowY, 1, 1, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL_FLOAT, &z_cursor);
    gluUnProject(windowX, windowY, z_cursor, modelview, projection, viewport, &x, &y, &z);
    printf("%lf %lf %lf\n", x, y, z);
}
}
```

Does anyone know why the errors happened and how to fix it? Or is there another way to achieve the goal "moving the object to the position of mouse"?

Comment: One problem is that you're setting the projection matrix after you draw the points. So it will only be used for the next frame. You need to move the setup of the projection to the start of the draw function.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 
But I still got the wrong answer. For example, I click on the point(0,0,0), the result is (1.22, 1.12, 1.09).